# How do I tell if a DOM element is HTML or SVG?

Tags: html, dom, svg

I am writing a piece of infrastructure that needs to be applied differently to HTML elements versus SVG elements. Given a DOM node, how can I tell if it''s an SVG or HTML element?

Comment: Don't agree that this needs a code sample to explain the problem, the question is clear from the text.

Comment: @David not only is the close reason absurd, but you will see that the question got a solid answer that would be of use to others within 30 minutes. I have no idea what the guys were thinking here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You may try something like the following:

```js
if(document.getElementById("el") instanceof SVGElement) {
    console.log("It's an SVG element");
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="300" height="300">
  <g id="firstGroup">
    <rect id="el" width="100" height="50" x="40" y="20" fill="blue" />
    <text x="40" y="100">This is a basic SVG document!</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note that the `<svg>` element itself is actually an HTML element *containing* `SVG` elements - which means that, perhaps surprisingly, the `<svg>` HTML element is *not* an `SVG` element, hence:

```
console.log(document.createElement("svg") instanceof SVGElement)) // => false
```

Comment: I did if(element.getBBox){  to check if the element had a getBBox method.  Certain functions/methods only exist for SVG elements.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Checking `instanceof  SVGElement` on an `<svg>` will return true. The reason why your demo returns false is because you need to create svg element using `document.createElementNS` not `document.createElement`. Therefore when checking by using `instanceof SVGElement` it will return `true`, not `false`. Example: `console.log(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg") instanceof SVGElement) // => true`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how cross browser compatible it is but I was poking through the DOM properties and saw a `ownerSVGElement` which seems promising?

Here goes what I was toying around with: http://jsbin.com/uMIronal/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Note that this approach doesn't work unless the SVG element has already been added to a document - for example, `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle").ownerSVGElement` will be `null`, so `instanceof` is more reliable in that way, and [also performs better](https://jsperf.com/check-if-svg-element/1).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell one thing from other things apart, then you may list all their characteristics, find the most distinguashable ones and validate them with typical use cases.

```js
function getElementType(el) {
  switch (el.namespaceURI) {
    case 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml': return 'html'; // for HTML/XHTML
    case 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg': return 'svg'; // for SVG
    case 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML': return 'math'; // for MathML
    default: return 'xml';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a test in a **virtual DOM** environment (e.g JSDOM) you may not be able to retrieve the correct SVG element types or namespace info.

In this case you may check whether an element is wrapped in an SVG via [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest?retiredLocale=de) method (it also returns true if the current element is a SVG).

```js
console.log(isSVGEl(svg))
console.log(isSVGEl(foreignObject))
console.log(isSVGEl(aHtml))
console.log(isSVGEl(aSvg))
console.log(isSVGEl(filter))
console.log(isSVGEl(svgInForeign))


function isSVGEl(el) {
  let inSVG = el.closest('svg') ? true : false
  let inForeignObject = el.closest('foreignObject') ? true : false
  let isSVGElement = inSVG && inForeignObject ? (el.nodeName === el.nodeName.toLowerCase() ? true : false) : true


  let data = {
    nodeName: el.nodeName,
    inSVG: inSVG,
    inForeignObject: inForeignObject,
    isSVGElement: isSVGElement
  }
  console.log(data)
  return inSVG
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <filter id="filter">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>
  
  <g id="g">
    <rect id="rect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0"  fill="#ccc" />
    
    <a id="aSvg" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject">
      <text id="text" x="50%" y="50%" font-size="10%" fill="blue">Svg link</text></a>

  </g>
  <!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG -->
  <foreignObject id="foreignObject" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:5px">
      foreignObject:
      <a id="aHtml" href="#">HTML link</a>
      
      <svg id="svgInForeign" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  </svg>


</div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Obviously, this requires your virtual DOM parser to support `closest()`.
The above example also checks HTML elements within a ´`. In this case you need to my include additional data for you needs: e.g if element is wrapped in a foreignObject (so part of an SVG) but essentially a HTML element.